# Linux Mint. Энергопотребление

Tags: linux, linux-mint, энергосбережение

На ноуте Mint разряжает батарею в 4 раза быстрее, чем семерка. Утилита Jupiter(для Ubuntu) для настройки производительности и т. п. не ставится. Может кто-нибудь знает похожие проги для Mint'a, или другой способ, как решить проблему энергопотребления в Linux Mint?

Comment: Странно, у меня Ubuntu 10.10 на ноуте нормально, почти как хрюша потребляет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего производитель вашего ноутбука писал проприетарный (закрытый) драйвер для чипсета. Следовательно он то знал, как замедлять куллер, снижать частоту процессора. Linux (Ubuntu и Mint в частности) же этого не знает, т.к. там используется более общий, но менее функциональный с точки зрения вашего чипсета драйвер. И дело тут не в утилите. Так что, скорее всего, решения вашей проблемы не существует. Остается надеяться, что когда-то выйдет новый драйвер, который будет полноценно держать управление питанием.

Comment: Это не совсем верно. Разные дистрибутивы поставляются с разными наборами патчей на ядро и, как следствие, с разной поддержкой железа. Так что в общем случае решением является попытка найти другие дистрибутивы. Например, мой ноут тише всего работает с opensuse, но я его не использую из-за нестабильности поставляемого софта.

Answer (score 1):

Поищи утилиту под названием `powertop` - посмотри что она скажет... Так-же нужно смотреть что у тебя там с процессами (см. команда `top`) может-быть кто-то процессор ест.

Comment: У одного моего знакомого nemo сжирал добрую половину ресурсов у МОЩНОГО процессора (Core i7)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с повышенным энергопотреблением известна еще с 2.6.38, причина скорее всего в кривом биосе.

Рецепт для Debian, возможно в mint конфиг лежит в другом месте:

1. Исправить в файле /etc/default/grub строку GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force"
2. Запустить update-grub

Действия выполнять от рута.

Если это не помогло, значит камрад SkyFox прав.

Answer (score 0):

Поставил недавно на десктоп Xubuntu 11.10. ИБП имеет индикатор мощности. Заметил немалое снижение потребления электричества. Попробуйте, может, поможет.